# Why is "this" scope wrong in a defined property?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I am creating a debounce function in my code, I have made a really simple example however when using it in combination with Object.defineProperty the value of "this" is questionable.

This is the code:

```
// Debounce a function call
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "debounce", {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function(ms, scope) {
        var fn = this,
            time = ms,
            timer;
        function debounced() {
            var args = arguments;
            if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function() { fn.apply(scope, args); }, time);
        }
        return debounced;
    }
});
```

And it is called with (where the .bind... is done as part of an external library):

```
function() {
    console.log(this.something);
}.debounce(300).bind(someObject)();
```

And it works, but the value of "this" cannot be used. Within the value function "this" points to the original function. Is there anyway I can get the bound scope with this design style?

## Example

```
var a = {
    b: function() {
        console.log(this.something);
    }.debounce(300),
};

var c = {
    something: true,
};

// I can't control this code -> 3rd party library
a.b.bind(c)();
```

Comment: wouldn't you pass `someObject` as the second argument `debounce` - like `}.debounce(300, someObject)();`

Comment: What do you want the `this` should refer and `scope` should refer here?

Comment: I did add the scope parameter to try and implement that but imagine this is being passed off to a 3rd party library which is calling: (function() { ... }.debounce(300)). I don't know what the someObject will be.

Comment: @Aruna Ideally there should be a way to access the bound object AND the bound object from the debounced function at call time.

Comment: I have added an example to try and explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `this` of `debounced` when `debounced` is called

in old school JS

```
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "debounce", {
    value: function value(ms) {
        var fn = this,
            time = ms,
            timer;
        function debounced() {
            var _this = this;
            var args = arguments;
            if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                return fn.apply(_this, args);
            }, time);
        }
        return debounced;
    }
});
```

or simpler in ES2015+

```
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "debounce", {
    value: function(ms) {
        var fn = this,
            time = ms,
            timer;
        function debounced() {
            if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, arguments), time);
        }
        return debounced;
    }
});
```

You can also remove enumerable:false, writable:false as false is the default value for these properties - makes the code a little smaller :p

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Been banging my head against the wall on this for ages!

Comment: You could drop `args` and use `arguments` in the ES2015 version since arrow functions don't include either one.

Comment: @squint I get the typescript error "The 'arguments' object cannot be referenced in an arrow function in ES3 and ES5." when I do that.

Comment: `arrow function in ES3 and ES5` ... that makes no sense, ES3 and ES5 didn't have arrow function!

Comment: Probably just a dodgy version of the Typescript compiler I have then :D Thanks for the help guys :)